# Dynamic Total Demand Cost SUM using different excel formulas SUMPRODUCT, INDEX and MATCH

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumproduct

**There are two sheets in my workbook - 1. Capacity and 2. Demand**

[image: Capacity Sheet]

[image: Demand Sheet]

I am trying to retreive the total demand cost for my dashboard, which will match each resource from "Demand" sheet and get the "Cost per Hours" from "Capacity" sheet and multiply with respective resource with "Demand Hours" from "Demand" sheet.

I manage to get the demand cost of each resource, however, I want total cost for all the resources.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CAPACITY!$B$2:$B$10,IFERROR(MATCH(DEMAND!$A2,CAPACITY!$A$2:CAPACITY!$A$10,0),0))*DEMAND!$B2,0)
```

Comment: Finally manage to update the formula with below
`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(INDEX(CAPACITY!$B$2:$B$10,IFERROR(MATCH(DEMAND!$A2:$A10,CAPACITY!$A$2:CAPACITY!$A$10,0),0))*DEMAND!$B2:$B10,0))`
let me know if there is better way to do this

Comment: I think you had a similar dashboard problem to obtain **Deficit/surplus**.  I have a formula solution but cannot find the question.  Can you post a link here?  Or am I misrembering?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69232069/dynamically-calculating-the-values-and-populating-them-on-the-dashboard-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment122374491_69232069.